# QWebView not loading Qt resource images

Tags: qt, qwebview

I have a QGraphicsWebView to which I construct a page by appending tags. For example:

```
webElement.appendInside("<img src=<img src=\"qrc:/img/ioLlogoTopLeft.png\" />");
```

This happens in a secondary QThread. I also use resources to set styling in the same thread:

```
defaultBaseFrame->setStyleProperty("background-image", "url(qrc:/img/ioLGradientTop.png)");
```

Both of these lines were working fine, but in the last few builds they've stopped working, and I've no idea why. Instead of an image I now get an empty frame, and the background fails to appear. The resource paths seem fine, and work fine in other (non web-view) parts of the program.

On the other hand, when I replace an image URL with a location on the internet (an http:// url), the image loads normally.

Is there some quirk to using resources in a multithreaded environment (or was that just a red-herring?) Resource images were working before, and I can't think of anything relevant in the code that I've changed recently.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. And not a particularly satisfying solution; more just a quirk of Qt. It turns out the problem started when I removed the (I assumed) redundant initialisation of the WebView to a blank page:

```
webView->setHtml("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
```

When I re-added it, images in resource files started working again. There didn't seem to be any other difference in functionality; all the other page elements render the same, just that one little quirk was fixed.

Recall that I'm building up the page from a blank DOM tree. I had falsely assumed that the above line was redundant because QWebView always inserts those boilerplate HTML tags automatically regardless, and *almost* everything works as it should either way.